# RNN to model DNA sequencing classification

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, rnn, sequence-to-sequence, gru

I have a DNA sequence dataset each mapped to a certain class.
e,g

**TCAGCCGAGAGCTCATCGATCGTACGT 2**

**ATGCAGTGCATCGATCGATCGTAGAAC 3**

Where the number after the sequence specifies the type of protein this sequence belongs to.

So my question can I use KMers and 1-HOT-Coding to classify these sequences through biLSTM.

Or this is not a possible concept and I would appreciate your feedback and suggestions on this task as I am new to Deep Learning.

Thank you.